# Django & PostgreSQL MemoryError + script not working correctly

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'll start by explaining the architecture of the project. There is a bot on aiogram, through which orders are created. Orders consist of lines (item), price, and order affiliation IDs.

Task:
The script will process all unpaid orders, and if the order has not been paid for more than N minutes, the product rows are returned to the product table, and the order is deleted.

My implementation:

```
while True:
            users = MyUser.objects.all().exclude(bot_username='null')
            now = timezone.now()
            for admin_user_obj in users:
                for order in User_purchase.objects.raw('SELECT id, time_created, chat_id, balance_to_return FROM user_purchases WHERE is_paid=FALSE and belongs=%s LIMIT 5', [admin_user_obj.id]):
                    if order.time_created + timezone.timedelta(minutes=admin_user_obj.booking_time) < now:
                        try:
                            bot_user = Bot_user.objects.get(belongs=admin_user_obj.id, chat_id=order.chat_id)
                            if order.balance_to_return:
                                bot_user.balance += order.balance_to_return
                            bot_user.active_orders -= 1
                            bot_user.save()
                            send_order_canceled(order, admin_user_obj)
                            for z in User_purchase.objects.raw('SELECT id, strings, item FROM user_purchases WHERE id=%s', [order.id]):
                                add_strings(z.item, z.strings)
                        except:
                            pass
                        order.delete()
```

SQL queries because MemoryError is thrown otherwise.

After launching and monitoring the logs, the script starts spamming me with the product line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdQyg.png)

And the client told me that his 1 line of goods turned into 23 million, and several lines in the reservation turned into 7 million lines. To say that it surprised me is to say nothing.

models.py

```
class User_purchase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_purchases'
        verbose_name = 'Платеж пользователя в боте'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Платежи пользователей в боте'

    chat_id = models.IntegerField()
    belongs = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.TextField()
    strings = models.TextField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=10,
        default=0
    )
    balance_to_return = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=10,
        default=0)
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    coupon = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=True)
    item = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    time_of_commission = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```

docker-compose

```
db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    command: >
      -c work_mem=512MB
      -c maintenance_work_mem=256MB
      -c max_wal_size=1GB

  premium_daemon:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py premium_daemon
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
```